# What does the %<-% operator do?

Tags: r

I am following along with the code of this post:

https://blogs.rstudio.com/tensorflow/posts/2019-09-30-bert-r/

And I am encountering this operator %<-% that I have never seen in R, and I am getting an error when I run the portion of the code that includes it.

I have tried looking in the documentation, I have also tried to use the magrittr package, but it is not defined there either.

This is the code that gives me the error:

```r
c(x_train,x_segment, y_train) %<-% 
dt_data('~/Downloads/jigsaw-unintended-bias-in-toxicity-classification/train.csv',2000)
```

and I am getting the following error when I run the code:

could not find function "%<-%"

Comment: Looks like it's ultimately from `{zeallot}`: https://github.com/r-lib/zeallot

Comment: Also see: https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-do-i-obtain-the-operator/13287

Comment: Thank you Brian, this is it.

Comment: @Carlos if you want to document what you found at those links and post it as an answer, you can answer your own question and accept it.

Comment: It could also be from `future`, though neither package is directly listed in the article. (**Edit**: on second thought ... it is more likely `zeallot`, not `future` ...)